# Connect Local Active MQ to remote IBM MQ

Tags: activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I'm new to active MQ.

I have a requirement to create a local Active MQ and connect it to a remote IBM MQ.

Can anyone help me on how to connect to Distributed Queue manager and Queues .

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache Camel to bridge between the two providers.  The routes can be run from within the broker, pull from the ActiveMQ queue and push to the WMQ Queue (or the other way around).  The concept is almost like the concept of a Channel in WMQ pulling from a transmit queue and pushing it to the appropriate destination on the remote queue manager.

Assuming you are using WMQ V7+ for all QMgrs and Clients, its simply a matter of learning how to set up the route and configure the connection factories. Older versions of WMQ and you may have to understand how to deal with RFH2 headers for native WMQ clients if they are the consumers.

The most simple route configured in spring would look like:

```
<route id="amq-to-wmq" >
  <from uri="amq:YOUR.QUEUE" />
  <to uri="wmq:YOUR.QUEUE" />
</route>
```

The "wmq" and "amq" would point to beans where the JMS components are configured.  This is where you would set up you connection factories to each provider and how the clients behave (transacted or not for example), so I'll hold off on giving an example on that.

This would go in the camel.xml (or whatever you name it) and get imported from your broker's XML.  ActiveMQ comes with several examples you can use to get you started using Camel JMS components.  Just take a look at the default camel.xml that comes with a normal install.